Reduction in Esri imagery basemap resolution when changing coordinate system of ArcGIS Pro map
When changing the coordinate system of my ArcGIS Pro project map from the default WGS 1984 Web Mercator (auxiliary sphere) to GDA 1994, the resolution of the Esri imagery basemap (and Google Maps tiled service layer) declines drastically. To the point where the imagery is not really useable for outputting quality maps. The difference in resolution is most noticeable at a scale of ~1:30,000, but it is visible across all scales.
I can't remember ever having this issue before, I have also talked to past colleagues who are unable to replicate the issue, and I have been unable to find examples of anyone having similar issues online.  I am currently using the most recent version of ArcGIS Pro (3.2.2).
Edit
With a bit of further investigation it seems to potentially be some sort of display issue in pro. The difference in quality is drastic in the map viewer as well as the layout viewer. However when I output maps the resolution seems to rectify (see images below). So it's not really an issue for outputting maps, but rather just off putting when using WGS 1984 Web Mercator basemaps in any other coordinate system.
Map outputs:


Project screenshots:



Honestly, my eyesight is not great, but I'm seeing maybe a bit of fuzziness in the display? But I have to really look. I think I do a reduction in the north-south stretching that occurs in 3857, but that's to be expected.

I don’t see any difference.
